# How can i use .predict method for tensorflow model which i downloaded from FTP server?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ftp

I have created tensorflow model, I uploaded it to FTP server and then I downloaded it. How can I use .predict method for that downloaded model?

This is function for uploading to FTP

```
def upload_model(self):
    domain_name, username, password = self._get_ftp_credentials()

    ftp = FTP(domain_name)
    ftp.login(user=username,
              passwd=password)

    ftp.cwd('chatbot_models')

    with open('models/models/model.h5', 'rb') as fp:
        ftp.storlines("STOR " + 'model.h5', fp)

    ftp.quit()
```

This is function for downloading from FTP

```
def _get_model(self):
    domain_name, username, password = self._get_ftp_credentials()

    ftp = FTP(domain_name)
    ftp.login(user=username,
              passwd=password)

    ftp.cwd('chatbot_models')

    filename = 'model.h5'

    model = open(filename, 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, model.write, 1024)

    ftp.quit()

    return model
```

When i try to use .predict method with downloaded model it says:

AttributeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object has no attribute 'predict'

Full code:

```
class QuestionAnswerer(DataProcessor):
    def __init__(self, json_data):
        super().__init__(json_data)
        self.model = self._get_model()
        self.tokenizer = self.create_tokenizer_obj()

    def _get_ftp_credentials(self):
        env_path = Path('../env') / '.env'
        load_dotenv(verbose=True, dotenv_path=env_path)

        domain_name = os.getenv("FTP_HOST")
        ftp_username = os.getenv("FTP_USERNAME")
        ftp_password = os.getenv("FTP_PASSWORD")

        return domain_name, ftp_username, ftp_password

    def _get_model(self):
        domain_name, username, password = self._get_ftp_credentials()

        with FTP(domain_name, username, password) as ftp:
            ftp.cwd('chatbot_models')

            with open('model.h5', 'wb') as file:
                ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + 'model.h5', file.write)

        return file

    def get_answer(self, question):
        tags = self.get_tags()

        words = [question]
        X_test_tokens = self.tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(words)

        X_test_pad = pad_sequences(X_test_tokens, maxlen=len(tags), padding='post')
        results = self.model.predict(X_test_pad)
```

This is how I am testing my class and my model:

```
from socialworks_neural_networks import QuestionAnswerer
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import json

with open('questionss_responses.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

model = QuestionAnswerer(data)
model._get_model()

model_1 = load_model('model.h5')
```

Comment: _model = open(filename, 'wb')_ What do you expect that to do?

Comment: Doesn't it open the file so that I could write into it?

Comment: Yes-ish, but it’s awkward, for a few different reasons. You could just use a context manager to write the response to a file, then later open the file again, this time to read the contents.

Comment: How does a working code with `predict` look like if you work with a local file?

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I assume you know how load the model from a local file. Do you? Can you show us a code for that? And we can then help you with changing that code to load from FTP.

Comment: Just updated the code

Comment: I do not see how your update answers my question.

Comment: Do you mean: model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('model.h5') ?

Comment: As you save the downloaded file to a physical local file, so why don't you do the same  after the download? Or do you want to avoid creating the local file?

Comment: I think now I understand the the problem but after I use load_model('model.h5') I get a different error: """OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: model.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}""", even though the downloaded file itself is in the same directory

Comment: Maybe the problem lies in that this code is in a package and I am trying to access it from a tests directory? The downloaded file ('model.h5') is in tests directory as well